# How to off-set Columns in Susy Grid System?

Tags: css, sass, offset, susy-sass, susy

I want to Off-Set Columns using Susy, like off-setting columns in Bootstrap.

I tried to use

```
@include span(4 at 4);
```

But that doesn't work.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just found out how to do this.

There is two functions (or mixins) called "push" and "pull"

```
@include push(4);
@include pull(4);
```

And that's really it :)

Comment: Are you applying this to the element that has the `@include span(X of X)`, or to the child element?

Comment: @ChristianFazzini, Yes, I'm adding this to the element that is controlled by the `@include span(x)`, so the element would look like this `@include span(4); @include push(4)`

Comment: Thanks. I <3 Susy! :D